Cancellation of fractional parts after successive flooring
Let $n$ be an integer, $q_n=\lfloor\sqrt{2}n\rfloor$, $r_n = \sqrt{2}n-q_n$ (the fractional part of $\sqrt{2}n$) and $e_n = r_n + r_{q_n}$ (the sum of the two consecutive fractional parts).
We obviously have $0<|e_n|<2$, however, numerical experiments show that $\inf|e_n|\approx 0.707106(=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}?)$ and $\sup|e_n|\approx 1.707106(=\frac{2+\sqrt{2}}{2}?)$. How can we show this?
Note that if we replace $\sqrt{2}$ by another quadratic number, it also seems we can get better bounds than $(0, 2)$. For example, for $\phi$, I conjecture $\inf|e_n|= 1$ and $\sup|e_n|= 3-\phi \approx 1.38196$. However, if we drop the requirement that $n$ is integer, or replace $\sqrt{2}$ by a random value, we get $0$ and $2$ as $\inf$ and $\sup$.

Ok, that was in fact not that hard.
$$q_{q_n} = \lfloor \sqrt{2} \lfloor \sqrt{2}n\rfloor\rfloor = \lfloor \sqrt{2} (\sqrt{2}n-r_n)\rfloor = \lfloor 2n-r_n\sqrt{2}\rfloor $$
Thus if $r_{n}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, then $r_{q_n} = 1-r_n\sqrt{2}$ and if $r_{n}> \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, then $r_{q_n} = 2-r_n\sqrt{2}$.
A quick analysis show that the minimum of $r_n+r_{q_n}$ is attained for $r_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, giving the $\inf$, and the maximum is attained for $r_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\varepsilon$, giving the $\sup$.
For $\phi$, this is a bit more tricky:
$$\begin{align}
q_{q_n} &= \lfloor \phi \lfloor \phi n\rfloor\rfloor = \lfloor \phi (\phi n-r_n)\rfloor\\
& = \lfloor \phi n+n-r_n\phi\rfloor\\
&= \lfloor \lfloor \phi n\rfloor+r_n+n-r_n\phi\rfloor
\end{align} $$
$r_n(\phi-1)\in [0, 1]$, so $r_{q_n} = 1-r_n(\phi-1)$ and $r_n + r_{q_n} = 1+r_n(2-\phi)$. This is minimal for $r_n=0$ and maximal for $r_n=1$.
